# Word choice between 'stem from' and 'ignite'

Tags: word-choice

I am writing my Statement of Purpose, and could someone possibly answer my questions here?

> My strong passion for education **stems from** my experience with Jack
>   Liu.

In this sentence, would the phrase "*was ignited by*" be better here?

Comment: They have the same meaning. Only your word count is changed.

Comment: They don't have the same meaning at all... they both work, grammatically but they paint two different pictures.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on just how strong you wish to characterize your passion for education. To say that your passion "stems from" an incident produces an image of your interest growing like a plant from a seed. To say that it was "ignited" suggests that your passion is like a fire, and this is a much more dramatic and intense characterization.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'd like show my strong passion for education here, so I guess the word 'ignited' would be better here?

Comment: It depends on your audience. Education is usually considered to be a fairly sedate and nurturing field, so "ignite" might be seen as overstating your level of interest. Then again, if you think it fits you, go ahead.

Comment: I am writing a Statement of Purpose for graduate application, so the audience might be professors in the field of education. Could you possibly tell me which one is better, in you opinion? Thank you~~

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience at all in this field. I'd suggest you talk to a professor.

Comment: okay~thank you for your help anyway. I really appreciate it XD

Answer (score -1):

> STEM
>
> verb
>
> 1. (stem from)
>
> originate in or be caused by

Originate is synonymous with *Arouse*, *Inflame*, *Kindle* and:

> IGNITE
>
> verb
>
> arouse or inflame (an emotion or situation):  "the words ignited new
>   fury in him"

If you **arouse** a passion, you are the *originator* of said passion. If you **inflame** a passion, you are the *stem* of said passion.

This is semantics.

Comment: No, it's not semantics. "stem from" is boring and passive.  "Ignited by" is active and exciting. "My love for him was ignited by our mutual desires" vs "My love for him stemmed from our mutual desires"... The first one is exciting... the second one is clinical. They are NOT the same.

Comment: i respect your opinion